# Fix "Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_redirect()"

Tags: php, http-redirect

I'm a pretty new PHP programmer, and as I was trying to call the PHP `http_redirect()` function, this error came up:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function http_redirect() in **D:\xampp1.8.3\htdocs\Bank\create.php** on line **28**

I called it just like they did in the examples on the [php site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php) like this:

```
http_redirect("show.php", array("status" => "new"), true, HTTP_REDIRECT_PERM);
```

I'm more familiar with `header()`, but I don't know how to send in an something similar to `http_redirect()`'s params (the `array()`). I've tried doing `header("Location: show.php?status=new")` but that doesn't work for me.

Could somebody help with this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `pecl_http` installed?  `http_redirect` is provided in the PECL `pecl_http` package as stated in the link you've posted, but the `header("Location:...")` should work.  Can you post more code where you are using the `header` function.

Comment: And if `header()` [doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php), so won't `http_redirect()`. A userland fallback is available in upgradephp.

Comment: Try an absolute url in your header("Location:") command. And make sure you did not output anything before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http_redirect` is also sending the same headers for location like you tried, so you don't really need `http_redirect`

1. Your error is `http_redirect` does not exist, so I think you don't have [pecl_http](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) installed like @vinodadhikary said
2. If `header("Location ...")` is not working maybe your headers are already sent (you can check this with the function `headers_sent`

   - **Example:**
     `if(!headers_sent()) header("Location http://YOURDOMAIN.abc/target.html");`
3. It is suggested to use absolute URLs for location header
4. In a comment on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/function.header.php#90050), Chrome doesn't perform a `Location:` instruction unless it gets a `Status:` first